# Add filter method for all setter methods in java

Tags: java, jackson

I have the following class, with all the getter-setter method.

```
public class Employee {

    @JsonProperty("FirstName")
    private String FirstName;

    @JsonProperty("LastName")
    private String LastName;

    @JsonProperty("MiddleName")
    private String MiddleName;

    @JsonProperty("Address")
    private String Address;

    public String getMiddleName() {
        return MiddleName;
    }

    public void setMiddleName(String middleName) {
        MiddleName = middleName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return LastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        LastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return FirstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        FirstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return Address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        Address = address;
    }

}
```

Also, I have below JSON string.

```
String jsonString = "{\"employee\": {\"FirstName\": \"FirstName++bb####**\",\"LastName\": \"LastName++bb####\",\"MiddleName\": \"MiddleName++bb####\",\"Address\": \"Address++bb####\"}}"
```

By using jackson API I am converting json string to java object. Here is my code

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
return mapper.readValue(jsonString, Employee.new);
```

Now I have to add a filter while mapping my JSON string to a java object, such that it will remove my special characters from all the fields.

We can achieve by updating setter methods. Ex.

```
public void setAddress(String address) {
        Address = address.replaceAll("[-+.^:,#,*,(,)]","");
    }
```

Is there any better way to add a filter in Jackson API or any other way to achieve this without updating setter method.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom deserializer, and can write your required logic in that deserializer. Here is how you can write your own deserializer - https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization

Snippet of how you can create custom deserializer:

```
public class MyDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<String> { 

    public MyDeserializer() { 
        this(null); 
    } 

    public MyDeserializer(Class<?> vc) { 
        super(vc); 
    }

    @Override
    public Item deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) 
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        String val = jp.getValueAsString();

        return val.replaceAll("[-+.^:,#,*,(,)]","");
    }
}
```

You can annotate your fields with your custom deserializer class like this:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = MyDeserializer.class)
private String address;
```

Then whenever JSON object will be deserialized to `Employee` class, logic in `MyDeserializer` will be used.

Comment: If you have to annotate every field like you show, I don't see that this adds any/much benefit.  I assume that the OP is looking for a solution that allows them to not have to add additional code for each individual field in the target class.  Is it possible to add this custom deserializer globally (per ObjectMapper instance), or at least on a per-class basis?

Comment: Yes Deserializer annotation can be added on class level too. I have just given example of single field.

Comment: I would suggest that you add an example of doing that to your answer.  Can it be added globally by somehow adding it to the ObjectMapper so it applies to every class being deserialized?  I don't know if the OP wants that, but I'm curious myself.

Comment: To make it globally work with `ObjectMapper`, you can make a static instance of `ObjectMapper`, configure it to use this deserializer, and use this instance everytime to deserialize to java object.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in three steps.

1. Parse string to `JsonNode' (`JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(jsonString);`)
2. Iterate thru attributes and fix values.

```
Iterator<String> elements = ((ObjectNode) jsonNode).fieldNames();
        while (elements.hasNext()){
            String name = elements.next();
            String oldText = jsonNode.get(name).asText();
            String newText = transform(oldText);
            ((ObjectNode) jsonNode).set(name, new TextNode(newText));
        }
```

3. Finally convert to DTO (`mapper.convertValue(jsonNode, Employee.class);`)

Answer (score 0):

I don't wanna duplicate the content which already exists here [Serialize Only Fields that meet a Custom Criteria with Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-field-custom-criteria). The only thing we need to implement the filter logic.

Comment: OP has asked regarding deserializing the field and not serializing the field.

Comment: Doh!  Great point @JigneshM.Khatri :). Can this same approach be applied to deserialization?

Comment: I have already posted an answer of how we can use custom logic in deserialization (use custom deserializers).

Comment: @JigneshM.Khatri Read the question properly.

Comment: @CryptoFool I am suggesting an approach to achieve his end result, Not deserialization.

Comment: @YuvarajS I have commented after reading (and UNDERSTANDING) only. Converting JSON string to Object is known as "Deserialization". OP want to convert JSON String to Java Object (means deserialization). Also OP want to remove junk characters in this process, and need any way (not just filter) to achieve this task.